# How to use x-message-ttl in node-amqp?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp, ttl

How to set `x-message-ttl` for queue RabbitMQ? I use node-amqp package.

`connection.queue('echo', {autoDelete: false, durable: true, "x-message-ttl":20000});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x-message-ttl` is an argument. Arguments are passed under `arguments` options property, so something like

```
connection.queue('echo', {
    autoDelete : false,
    durable    : true,
    arguments  : {
        "x-message-ttl" : 20000
    }
});
```

should do the job.

For more details see [queue.js source code](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp/blob/2a8e3505f9af598ab41ee56de99502b1222f0960/lib/queue.js#L409) and [`queue.declare` AMQP method documentation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.declare)

Answer (score 1):

I am using the `x-expire`s argument instead of `x-message-ttl`.

```
connection.queue('echo',{
    autoDelete:false,
    durable:false,
    arguments:{
        "x-expires":20000
     }
});
```

It is marking my Queue as Exp in the rabbit console but not deleting it after 20 seconds.
I don't know what I am doing wrong